# What version of Go is used to compile dependencies?

Tags: go, compilation

Whenever compiling a Go program, is same version of Go used to compile the main code as well dependency code ?

Comment: @Volker: No longer true, with Go 1.21.

Comment: @JonathanHall True, it now uses the toolchain selected which is a bit more complicated that "you invoked". The basic answer to the question is still "Yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and has a somewhat nuanced answer, that has changed over the years.

For older versions of Go, the answer was simple: Every dependency was compiled with whichever version of Go you're running locally.  If you were running Go 1.9, and you had dependencies built for Go 1.10, the compiler would be none the wiser, and attempt to compile the Go 1.10 code using Go 1.9. So long as no new features were used in that dependency, it would all work fine. Likewise, if you had a dependency written for Go 1.8, it would also be compiled using Go 1.9.

However, for modern versions of Go, and any projects (or dependencies) using a `go.mod` file, behavior is different.  From the [Go Modules Reference](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) we learn that:

> - For packages within the module, the compiler rejects use of language features introduced after the version specified by the go directive. For example, if a module has the directive go 1.12, its packages may not use numeric literals like 1_000_000, which were introduced in Go 1.13.

What this means is that your dependencies will only use features available in their *declared versions* of Go.  They're still built using the modern Go runtime, however.  So any performance enhancements, security improvements, etc, found in your version of Go, which is newer than the dependency's declared version, are still used.

Further, the next line of the same document says:

> - If an older Go version builds one of the module’s packages and encounters a compile error, the error notes that the module was written for a newer Go version. For example, suppose a module has go 1.13 and a package uses the numeric literal 1_000_000. If that package is built with Go 1.12, the compiler notes that the code is written for Go 1.13.

So this means that if you attempt to build a program using Go 1.19, and one of the dependencies declares version 1.20 *and* there is a compilation error, the compiler output will inform you of the potential compatibility problem.  If there are no compilation errors, you'll probably never notice the difference (because presumably the dependency which declared 1.20 isn't actually using any new 1.20 compiler features).

---

### Update for Go 1.21

As of Go 1.21, the Go version specified in `go.mod` or `go.work` is considered a strict minimum requirement. It will also, by default, automatically download a newer toolchain, if your current toolchain is older than the one specified as required in `go.mod`. Read more in the [Go 1.21 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.21#tools).

---

### Update for Go 1.22

As of Go 1.22, this will has a much more noticeable impact than before, mostly relating to the [less error-prone loop variable scoping](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60078) change. This changed the way loop variables are handled in a non-backward compatible way. Any module that declares `go 1.21` or earlier will use the old looping semantics, and any declaring `go 1.22` or newer will use the new looping semantics. This is the first noticable time that Go has broken its backward compatibility promise, though arguably for good reason (since this loop variable thing trips up virtually everyone).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the dependencies are compiled with the same compiler as is used for your code, and therefore it is the same version.

Go Modules may declare a [minimum version directive](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref) in their `go.mod` like so:

```
module example.com/mymodule

go 1.14
```

This influences compiler behaviour in two ways:

If the version specified in the dependencies `go.mod` is newer than the compiler's version, it will attempt to compile, but if an error is encountered then a message will be output to warn the user that the module has been written with a newer version of Go in mind.

If the version specified in the dependencies `go.mod` is older than the compiler's version, language features introduced after the specified version will be rejected.

Comment: thank you ! During my testing I found that, if compiler version is newer than the one specified in go.mod, compilation does not fail . Can you specify compilation would fail with newer Go version ? Did you mean to say "if older compiler is used" ?

Comment: I have not personally observed compilation failing when the Go compiler is of a newer version than the `go.mod` of a dependency module - if this were the case, updating your go compiler would be a very painful process. Can you be more specific about the error you receive?

Comment: I think we are on same page.  

new compiler, older version in go.mod --> compilation does not fail . 
old compiler, newer version in go.mod --> compilation fails if newer language features are used. 

This talk summarizes caveats regarding this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moS35OlJBmY&amp;t=867s&amp;pp=ygUPZ28gY21wYXRpYmlsaXR5 

Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes - I misread your comment. I do believe my answer is correct though. If you have a suggestion on wording that could make it clearer, and would make you happy to accept it - I'd be willing to make it :)

Comment: for last sentence in your answer :  since we are using newer compiler version than go.mod file,  language features will be accepted as long as they are compatible with compiler version right ? (in other words, version in go.mod does not matter since its older than compiler version)